# How to fix error with parts of the data passed through to partial being added as attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm pretty new to web design and I'm trying to set up my partial for my portfolio website. I want to be able to pass data through the ejs file to the partial in order to set the title and the description.

Using some information I already found on passing data, I created two variables, title and description and then pass them to the partials/header.ejs.

At the top of home.ejs:

```
<% var title = "The title for the Home Page" %>
<% var description = "The description for the home page" %>
<%- include partials/header.ejs {title: title, description: description} %>
```

Header.ejs

```
...
<head>
        <!-- Page Title -->
        <% if (title !== null) { %>
            <title><%= title %></title> 
        <% } else { %>
            <title>Default Title</title>
        <% } %>
        <!-- Page Description -->
        <% if (description !== null) { %>
            <meta name="description" content= <%= description %>>           
        <% } %>
...
```

I expect that the title should be set to the variable title ("The title for the Home Page") and that the description content attribute should be set to the variable description ("The description for the home page").

The title works correctly, but the description outputs:

```
<meta name="description" content="The" description for the home page>
```

with description, for, the, home, page all as attributes.

Is there something I'm just not seeing or am I using the <%= %> incorrectly?

Bonus question: Is what I'm doing reasonable/expected/standard, or is there a better way of accomplishing this task in typical sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to put description in double quotes

```
<meta name="description" content=" <%= description %>">
```